# Need to change the svg icon color in a styled DateInput

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

**Styled DateInput from grommet**. I tried changing the color this way.

```
const CalenderComponent = styled(DateInput)`
  svg {
    fill: #fff000 !important;
    stroke: #fff000 !important;
    path{
      fill: #fff000 !important;
      stroke: #fff000 !important;
    }
  }
`;
```

**Component:**

```
<CalenderComponent
  className='dateInput'
  format="mm/dd/yyyy"
></CalenderComponent>
```

[image: DateInput]

Code being rendered in my browser:
[image]

Comment: DateInput from grommet: https://v2.grommet.io/dateinput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the icon via `inputProps` of the DateInput component.

When using `format` prop, the icon is being rendered as part of the the input (i.e. MaskedInput), and the input accepts `inputProps` which allows icon customization as follows: `inputProps={{ icon: <Calendar color="red" /> }}`

Here is a fully working example:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Grommet, Box, DateInput } from 'grommet';
import { Calendar } from 'grommet-icons';
import { grommet } from 'grommet/themes';

export const Format = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const onChange = event => {
    ...
  };
  return (
    <Grommet theme={grommet}>
      <Box align="center" pad="large">
        <Box width="medium">
          <DateInput
            inputProps={{ icon: <Calendar color="red" /> }}
            format="mm/dd/yyyy"
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Grommet>
  );
};
```

[image]

Note: when not using the `format` prop on DateInput, one could control the icon rendering via the `buttonProps` prop instead of `inputProps`, more details on the [grommet's documentations](https://v2.grommet.io/dateinput?#buttonProps).